# Why aren't these continue statements working in my loops?

Tags: c, while-loop, do-while, continue

I'm trying to translate the following for loop into a while and a do-while loop, but for some reason the code breaks before it ever gets into the actual loop.

Here's what I'm trying to replicate:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{ int y;

  for (y=1;y<10; y++)
  { if (y == 5)
      continue;
    printf("%2d", y);
  }

  printf("\ny=%2d\n",y);

  return 0;
}
```

Here are my attempts at making equivalent while and do-while loops:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int y;

  y = 1;
  while(y < 10)  // here's my while loop
    {
      if(y == 5)
        continue;
      printf("%2d", y);
      y++;
    }

  printf("\ny=%2d\n",y);

/********************
... and my do-while
********************/
  y = 1;
  do
    {
      if (y == 5)
        continue;
      printf("%2d", y);
      y++;
    } while(y < 10);

  printf("\ny=%2d\n",y);

  return 0;
}
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You want to learn how to use a debugger, so you can trace your code step by step inspecting the value of all relevant variables and how they change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a `for` loop, `continue` jumps to the third expression of the `for` statement, which increments the counter.

In a `while` loop, `continue` jumps to the next iteration immediately, skipping the increment.

Answer (score 3):

If the condition is met in your code, you don't increment the variable and so you get stuck in an infinite loop. Try

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int y;

  y = 0;
  while(++y < 10)  // here's my while loop
    {
      if(y == 5)
        continue;
      printf("%2d", y);
    }

  printf("\ny=%2d\n",y);
```

or the like.

Comment: You need to remove the y++

Comment: To prevent this sort of mistake, OP could use `for` loop instead

Comment: @Jackson: Ooops, fixed!

Comment: Although correct, I feel this `y = 0; while(++y < 10)` is more complex then necessary, and though tends to be even more error prone. I'd prefer `y = 1; while(y < 10) { ++y;`

Comment: @alk: Yep, lots of ways to skin cats.